# Backing up a Clash of Clans account on iPad without the game center

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios

I use the same apple ID across an iPhone and an iPad, but play a separate Clash of Clans account.

The first account, my iPhone, is registered on the game center.

On the iPad, I did not activate the game center, in order to prevent it synching data from my iPhone.

Unfortunately, I have run into a problem with the iPad, and I need to perform a system restore. In the process, I will naturally loose all my application data.

Is there any way to keep my second Clash of Clans account backed up? Or am I doomed to loose my progress with the factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

Supercell has a newish feature. Supercell id. If you set up a Supercell id it will save your village online. To transfer the game center village to Supercell id, check out this help page https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?s=supercell-id&f=migrating-your-game-accounts-to-supercell-id&p=web

Answer (score 0):

You could try logging in with you're Google account. If you downloaded the app from the Google Play store than you have an account. But mostly everybody has one now-days. When you log into Google on your CoC game it will automatically save you're progress unless you already have another village saved on the account, then you'd have to register a new account.

Comment: As far as I am aware, only android devices can link with google.

Answer (score 0):

What is always handy is to contact the help team on CoC, they normally answer within a week at most, and are up for a bit of banter also ;)

Comment: Facebook only gives you your friend list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a new Apple ID, and log in with that on the iPad GameCenter. Then see if the current game on the iPad will connect automatically to the new Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

On clash of clans the settings have an option to “link accounts”. Press this and another question comas up “is this the `old device` `new device`”. After that another question “choose the type of device you want to link:`iPhone, iPad or iPod` `I want to link another device`“ depending on weather you clicked “old” or “new” it will either give you a code or ask for a code.

> NOTE: keep both devices on while linking