# I have the same village in two different devices and accounts, how can I separate it?

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios

The village that loads in my device (ios) loads in another device too, but now that we tried using two different accounts, the same old village still loads.

Whenever the game is started in any of the two devices, the Game Center welcomes us with the welcome message, and the best part is the game is not linked to any of the devices, which means I still have the choice of linking the game to another device. But I want to keep it simple - one village in one device with my account!

Can any one help me out?

Comment: generally your logged in in the game as well as the OS. 

That said, it is almost impossible for us to offer game help, if you fail to tell us what game you are talking about.

I am assuming Clash of Clans. On the basis that the same question has been asked here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227570/second-account-not-under-the-game-center.

While the question has not been answered, if that is you question, wait for a response on your first question, instead of posting it again.

Answer (score 3):

Delete your version of Clash of Clans, download it again, but don't open it. Then log out of your Apple ID. Start up Clash of Clans, and start your village. Then log back into your Apple ID. It should work, and it might ask you if you want to combine your account. Simply tap the No button.